# Is there a way to have successive pandas accessor

Tags: python, pandas

We can create custom pandas accessor by registering a class with the decorator:

```
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("my_accessor")
```

Is there a way to have successive accessor, in a such a way that it could be used as such:

```
df.my_accessor_1.my_accessor_2., ...,.my_accessor_n
```

The idea is to have a hierarchical ordering of my accessor.

I can't really find out how accessor are implemented.

Comment: You might want to provide a reproducible example as code and a example of use case with data.

Comment: If each of your accessors returns an object (maybe another dataframe?) that has the next accessor, i believe it should work

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs, indeed, but I would like some accessor to have the same name. That's why it would be convenient to have them accessed via different "parent" accessor. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.